# Is "Cocamidopropyl Betaine" vegetarian and/or vegan?

Tags: veganism, cosmetics

I have this shampoo which has an ingredient called **"Cocamidopropyl Betaine"**, is this vegetarian and/or vegan?

A quick Google doesn't reveal anything regarding vegetarianism of the ingredient.

EDIT 1:

I found this [link](http://veganeasm.tumblr.com/post/146269026850/cocamidopropyl-betaine) according to which it is made out of coconut oil and **betaine** but I have no idea what is **betaine** and where it comes from. The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betaine) on **betaine** is beyond my understanding and doesn't appear to have information on how and from what it is produced.

EDIT 2:

Here is the link to the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocamidopropyl_betaine) on the ingredient but I still don't know if it's vegetarian and/or vegan.

EDIT 3:

Further reading shows that Cocamidopropyl Betaine is made by reacting dimethylaminopropylamine with fatty acids from coconut oil. Dimethylaminopropylamine is made via a reaction between dimethylamine and acrylonitrile and dimethylamine is found in both animals and plants which would suggest that it might not be vegetarian.

Comment: In the first link provided it says:  Obtained from: coconut oil + betaine

Comment: Yep, as far as I understand it becomes a betaine once it is made. It is made by reacting Dimethylaminopropylamine with fatty acids from coconut oil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article on Cocamidopropyl betaine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocamidopropyl_betaine)

> Cocamidopropyl betaine (CAPB) is a mixture of closely related organic compounds derived from coconut oil and dimethylaminopropylamine <sup>[citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocamidopropyl_betaine#cite_note-1)</sup>

[Dimethylaminopropylamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethylaminopropylamine) is usually synthesised from [Acrylonitrile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylonitrile) which is produced using ammonia (produced from hydrogen and nitrogen in the Haber process) and propylene (a hydrocarbon from crude oil or possibly plant sources) and [Dimethylamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethylamine) which is [apparently](https://www.google.com/patents/US1926691) produced from methanol (an alcohol) and ammonia (although dimethylamine is found in animals, it is not derived from animal sources in the chemical industry).

So, cocamidopropyl betaine is not derived from animals.

Comment: Look at my last edit.